# How do I find the row name for columns that have a ratio of above 4? R

Tags: r, dataframe

I've managed to calculate the ratio of my rows with the following:
`dfratios <- df$row1/df$row2`
but I now need to find the corresponding row names for all of these ratios, I've tried using row.names but unfortunately, it's now working.

Additionally, I've also tried using `(df3 %>% filter(dfratios[dfratios > 3]))` but that has just given me the following error:

> Error in `filter()`:
> ! Problem while computing `..1 = df3Ratios[df3Ratios > 2]`.
> ✖ Input `..1` must be of size 789 or 1, not size 71.
> Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use dplyr to create the new variable an then filter after

```
df %>% 
  mutate(ratios = row1/row2) %>% 
  filter(ratios > 3)
```